# Edit Event click button 'X' in Java?

Tags: java, awt

When I open 2 frames: `frame1.setEnabled(false), frame2.setVisible(true)`. When I hit the button "X" then *frame2* close and want to set the enable frame1 (true), then how?

Comment: use a window listener and implement the `windowClosing` method:    `@Override
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    
   }`

Comment: `then how ?` how what ?  How to close one and enable the other? How to link this to a button click ? Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Use a `JDialog`, then you won't need to care

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Comment: typos fixed, markdown set

Answer (score 0):

just create event handler/listener, on event onClose(or similar)
maybe useful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html